# Uncaught ReferenceError: datos is not defined. ¿Como se soluciiona esto?

Tags: javascript

buenas, pues como pone ene el titulo me salta este error cuando le doy al boton de guardar los datos de el formulario para despues tratar de recuperarlos mediante El DNI, el caso es que tras muchos cambios no consigo averiguar el porque me salta este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mas exactamente esto es lo que me pone el error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: datos is not defined

> ```
> guardar file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/EJER formulario/finalizar.js:37
> ```

A continuacion paso el codigo mas el html

```
function guardar() {

    console.log("entra");
    
    datos.nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    datos.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    datos.edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
    datos.etsex = document.getElementById('etsex').value;
    datos.tlf = document.getElementById('tlf').value ;
    datos.estado_civil = document.getElementById('estado_civil').value;
    datos.seleccion= document.getElementById('seleccion').value;
    datos.txtdesc = document.getElementById('txtdesc').value;

    var datos = {

        
    }


    /*datos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI));*/
    sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI, JSON.stringify(datos));



}
   


function recuperar(){
    console.log("entra");
    var guardaDNI = document.getElementById('guardaDNI').value;

    if(sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI)){
        console.log("Pilla el item")
        var datos = sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI);
        console.log(datos.modalidad);
    }else{
        window.alert("No hay datos del DNI : "+guardaDNI);
        document.getElementById('guardaDNI').value = "";
    }

}
```

Y el html

```
              <tr>
                <td class='labels'></td>
                <td>
                  <input disabled type="button" value="Enviar" id="Enviar">
                  <input type="button" value="Validar" name="validar" id="validar">
                  <input type="button" value="Borrar" name="borrar" id="borrar">
                  <input type="button" value="guardar" name="guardar" id="guardar">
                  
                </br>

                <form id = "formrecuperar" action = "">
                Introduzca aquí el DNI para recuperar los datos: <input type = "text" id = "guardaDNI" name = "guardaDNI"></br></br>
                <input type = "button" value = "recuperar" name = "recuperar" id = "recuperar">
                </form>
```

Comment: De donde viene tu variable `datos`?, pues el mensaje es muy claro, no tienes definida la variable `datos` y estas tratando de usarla

Comment: Es mejor que la variable ses un parámetro y cuando llames a la función le pasas esa variable, así evitas errores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo diria que tienes los parametros al reves:

```
document.getElementById('nombre').value = datos.nombre;
document.getElementById('email').value = datos.email ;
document.getElementById('edad').value = datos.edad;
document.getElementById('etsex').value = datos.etsex;
document.getElementById('tlf').value = datos.tlf;
document.getElementById('estado_civil').value = datos.estado_civil;
document.getElementById('seleccion').value = datos.seleccion;
document.getElementById('txtdesc').value = datos.txtdesc;
```

deberia ser:

```
datos.nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
datos.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
datos.edad ....
```

aunque efectivamente, antes necesitas crear la variable datos, por ejemplo:

var datos = {};

la siguiente linea no seria necesaria, datos ya contendria los valores, que para eso se los has asignado antes.

```
datos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI));
```

espero haberte ayudado.

saludos.

Comment: Tiene sentido ponerlo de esa forma pero sigue saliendo el mismo error, aun así lo actualizare como tu lo has puesto a ver si alguien conoce el porque de ese fallo

Comment: Al final si lo resolvi pero tengo ahora otros problemas

Comment: en la respuesta que pones solo faltaria declarar la variable antes de asignarle los datos

Comment: No ha hecho falta al fin al lo cambie por un local storage y si me los guarda pero ahora tengo otros problemas, estoy elaborando una nueva pregunta porque no quiero que los edits se mezclen con esta ya que esta pregunta es sobre como guardar los datos